# Isn't it possible to use 'Repeats' in the lookaheads for boost:regex?

Tags: c++, regex, boost, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to extract some variables in my C++ code nested in blocks. For example, if I have

```
        DEL_TYPE_NONE,
            DEL_TYPE_DONE,
    DEL_TYPE_WAIT,
```

I'd like to match:

**"DEL_TYPE_NONE"

"DEL_TYPE_DONE"

"DEL_TYPE_WAIT"**

I made my pattern like this:

std::string pat("(?<=^[ \\t]?)[A-Z0-9_]+(?=,$)");

but I'm keep getting error message when compiler is trying to read my pattern. I don't understand but there is problem with **? mark after \\t**? If I get rid of ? mark then it compiles and find only **"DEL_TYPE_WAIT"**

Why can't I use Repeats in the Lookahead? What can I try next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. **No** from this [manual](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html)

> Lookbehind
>
> (?<=pattern) consumes zero characters,
>   only if pattern could be matched
>   against the characters preceding the
>   current position **(pattern must be of
>   fixed length).**

Answer (score 0):

Just based on POSIX I'd say your regex is "DEL_TYPE_([ND]ONE|WAIT),"

That's just based on what you've listed above.  I would say that the actual issue is with you double escaping the t; you should probably do [ \t\s]* since there may not be just zero or one tab/space.

Comment: the code I show above is just an example.
real one is more complex thought.
thank you anyway ^^